# Meaning of "will" + present perfect

Tags: meaning, modal-verb

> Das Handy-Signal, das der türkische Geheimdienst in Syrien geortet haben will, könnte für die Eltern der beiden seit Tagen verschwundenen Österreicherinnen zur traurigen Gewissheit werden.

What is the meaning of "will geortet haben" here? A translation into English would be something like "want to have located", but that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means the signal "that they claim to have located", i.e. it's unconfirmed.

Answer (score 1):

In my honest opinion the "will" suggests a possible pretence from the Turkish Intelligence.

I think it introduces the idea of a (deliberate ?) false notification into the readers mind.

Please correct my English in case.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to think of it is if they had said "They have allegedly located blah blah." Its a journalistic trick to hedge their opinion in case they turn out to be wrong.